# WCF REST POST XML

Tags: namespaces

Whats the best way that I can create wcf rest post that accepts xml document(with out any query string)?

Comment: You may want to reword your question since I see people are starting to vote to close. It's a bit vague but I think I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept a XElement as a single parameter with no placeholders in the UriTemplate.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="DoSomething")]
public XElement DoSomething(XElement body) {
    ...
    return new XElement("Result");
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I'm facing a similar problem...would you please address the namespace aspect in the original question...I think he/she is asking how to handle the namespace that's in the xml payload. w/o that being taken care, the request will get a 400 error. thanks!

Comment: I think the asker edited out the 'namespace' part...but that's the google keyword that led me here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very very broad and hard to answer.

To learn more about WCF REST, check out the [WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) and the WCF REST [screen cast series by Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/browselibrary.aspx?technology=WCF+REST) - they should both help you understand the basics, and if you have a more focused, a more clearly formulated answer about something in those learning materials, come and ask again.

The Pluralsight screencasts in particular are very helpful and easy to understand - 15 to 20 minute tutorial on how to do certain things with WCF REST - e.g. [HTTP Plain Old XML Service](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/howtovideo.aspx?a=aaron-skonnard&n=http-plain-xml-services) or a lot of other topics, too (ATOM syndication and a lot more). Check it out!